# Error in Azure Service Fabric Explorer when scaling down the VM's using VM Scale Set

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

So we have set up a scenario of auto scaling of VMs using VM scale set. SF explorer shows that a new node got added. But when the VMs are scaling down, SF explorer is not automatically removing the node and its showing error/unhealthy. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. SF Explorer Nodes are a reflection of what the SF system services (FM specifically) knows about the number of Nodes the cluster had/has. When you scaled the VMSS down, the VM was deleted, but FM still thinks that the node (that mapped to the VM that was deleted) will come back. So SFX shows that Node (albeit the health may be error or unknown).

In order to make sure that when a VM is removed, the Node is also gone, you have two options.

1) Choose a durability level of Gold or Silver (available soon) for the node types in your cluster, this will give you the infrastructure integration (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-capacity/) which will then automatically remove the Nodes from our system services (FM )state when you scaled down.

2) Once the VM instance has been scaled down, you will need to call the Remove-ServiceFabricNodeState cmd with the appropriate Node name : refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125993.aspx for details on the CMD

Hope this helps

Chacko
( https://twitter.com/chackod)